ViewRootImpl ViewRootImpl action cancel Messages
Recently, I am seeing a a TON of these messages generated when debugging my MAUI app :
[ViewRootImpl] [ViewRootImpl] action cancel - 1, eccen:1.163763
What is this, what does it mean and how might I turn it off?  It obfuscates the rest of my logging...

Have you tried other apps? Will this be the case with other apps?

@JessieZhang-MSFT : Yes.  It happens with other very simple apps.    I'm just interesting in understanding what the logged message means, and if there is a way of turning it off.

I didn't have such a problem. What's version of your visual studio? You can try to update it to the latest version.

I'm on Version 17.10.6.  Will try the upgrade to 17.11.6

Waiting for your good news. :)

@JessieZhang-MSFT : That took care of it.  After the update, those pesky debug messages are gone.  Thx!

Congrats. As a summary, I will post it as an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems. Thanks for your support and feedback.  :)

I didn't have such a problem for my visual studio of the newer version.
So you can update your visual studio to the latest version which will optimize some problems, and then try again.

Upgrading to 17.11.6 resolved this.
